# t-datepicker Month slide to left after select

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I use the t-datepicker (demo: https://t-datepicker.getqwerty.com/demos.html). If I click on a date on the right calendar (next month) with the calendar open, this month will slide to the left. How can I prevent this?
Thank you

Comment: Looking at the documentation, there doesn't seem to be a way I'm afraid. I've also checked if you can use some sort of callback to trigger after selecting the checkin date and then set the view to a specific month, but you can't do that last thing either. I do believe the standard behaviour is the desired one though. If you think otherwise, just file an issue on Github: https://github.com/crazychicken/t-datepicker/issues

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I saw that someone already has this problem. The question was not answered ...